# Uniqueness in BatchInserter of Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I am using a "BatchInserter" to build a graph (in a single thread). I want to make sure nodes (and possibly relationships) are unique. My current solution is to check whether the node exists in the following manner:

```
    String name = (String) nodeProperties.get(IndexKeys.CATEGORY_KEY);

if(index.get(IndexKeys.CATEGORY_KEY, name).size() > 0) 
        return index.get(IndexKeys.CATEGORY_KEY, name).getSingle();

    Long nodeID = inserter.createNode( nodeProperties,categoryLabel ); 

    index.add(nodeID, nodeProperties);   

    index.flush();
```

It seems to be working fine but as you can see it is IO expensive (flushing on every new addition - which i believe is a lucene "commit" command). This is slowing down my code considerably.

I am aware of [put if absent](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.9.M04/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/Index.html#putIfAbsent%28T,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [uniqueFactory](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.9.M04/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/UniqueFactory.html). As documented:

> By using put-if-absent functionality, entity uniqueness can be guaranteed using an index.
>   Here the index acts as the lock and will only lock the smallest part
>   needed to guaranteed uniqueness across threads and transactions. To
>   get the more high-level get-or-create functionality make use of
>   UniqueFactory

However, these are for transaction based interactions with the graph. What I would like to do is to ensure uniqueness of nodes and possibly relationships in a batch insertion semantics, that is faster than my current setup.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue i.e. creating unique nodes in batchinserter? I am stuck with same issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I encountered this problem, I just decided to go tyrant and force index values in my own. Can't you do the same? I mean, ensure uniqueness before you do the insertions?

Comment: I could, but my data size is immense (>20MM nodes) and to ensure uniqueness prior to insertion would be RAM intensive.

Comment: Do you already have the to-be-unique data or you can generate it on the fly?

Comment: it cannot be generated on the fly

Comment: @Peyman, I have used BathcInserter with amounts of approx. 100M-500M nodes and when I needed this kind of work to be done, I simply created a `HashMap` and pushed data into it on each insertion. This way I could flush the indices much less frequently and totally got rid of index queries. If you feel like your 20MM nodes will be too much to store in a map at once, use Guava's `Cache` with eviction and a custom loading strategy. This way, you *will* need to flush the index, but it still will be better than just flushing a node at a time.

Comment: @Peyman, to clarify: the map was of form "entry"->"did I already push the entry to DB" (Now that I think of it, even a `Set` will suffice.)

Comment: cdshines. Although a cache will work I would prefer low footprint solution. I could implement it in Lucene's FST (finite state transducer) but need to figure out how to include lucene into my project without neo complaining.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate the [MERGE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html) keyword in cypher.   I believe this will permit you to exploit your autoindexes without requiring you to use them yourself.   More broadly, you might want to see if you can formulate your bulk load in a way that is conducive to piping large volumes of cypher queries through the [neo4j-shell](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell.html).

Finally, as general pointers and background, you should check out [this information on bulk loading](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import)